# How to write query in Entity Framework with conditional multiple where condition?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, wcf

I am creating a wcf application which is connecting to DB to get some data for customer using Entity Framework. The concept is to search a customer based on the search parameters. User can provide all or few or at least one of the search parameters. But I am quite new in Entity Framework and getting confused on how to do this. I can do this in traditional SQL coding by considering If - Else condition in c# side.

This is my code which is getting the all of the paramters:

```
   var customers = from o in natCustomer.CustomerLists
                    select o;

    customers = customers.Where(c => c.Name == sName && c.Age == iAge
        && c.Gender == sGender && c.Height == dHeight && c.Weight == dWeight                             
        && c.Nationality == sNationality
        && c.EyeColor == sEyeColor && c.SpecialMark == sSpecialMark);
```

Please help me by suggesting how do I get the result with few or one parameter only.
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Entity Framework queries are "deferred" queries. They don't actually run until you start asking for results. This means you can build up a query in pieces and it will (mostly) work exactly like one bigger query.

In your case, you can do something like:

```
var customers = from o in natCustomer.CustomerLists
                select o;

if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(sName)) 
  customers = customers.Where(c => c.Name == sName);

if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(sNationality)) 
  customers = customers.Where(c => c.sNationality == sNationality);

if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(SpecialMark )) 
  customers = customers.Where(c => c.SpecialMark == SpecialMark);
```

etc. At the end, when you execute the `customers` query (for example, call `ToList` or use a `foreach` loop) EF will consolidate all of those smaller `Where` clauses into a single SQL query to run against your data.

Comment: I do exactly like this, IQueryable is your friend!

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I have been looking for. It really helped.

Comment: Is it allright when you are using LINQ and string queries together?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only want to find customers who match on all non-null parameters, an alternative approach is to include the null checks within the where query, and only compare the parameter to the customer data if the parameter is not null.

```
customers = customers.Where(c => (string.isNullOrEmpty(sName) || c.Name == sName) 
    && (iAge == null || c.Age == iAge)
    && (string.isNullOrEmpty(sGender) || c.Gender == sGender));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to determine if the given inputs are set or not. For a simplification I assume you receive your parameters as nullables. So you could add an additional condition, if the parameter is provided:

```
customers = sName == null ? customers : customers.Where(c => c.Name == sName);
customers = iAge == null ? customers : customers.Where(c => c.Age == iAge);
customers = sGender == null ? customers : customers.Where(c => c.Gender == sGender);
...
```